# Convergence of a series in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, consider the series 
$$
\lim_{n→\infty}\sum_{l,k=0}^n\frac{k^2x^ky^l}{l!}. 
$$
Then the series converges for $(x,y)$ in

1. $(-1,1)\times(0,\infty)$
2. $\mathbb R\times(-1,1)$
3. $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$
4. $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$

*As the series contains $k^2\cdot x^k$ which diverges if $|x|\not\lt1$ while the other in powers of $y$ converges for all $y$. So (1) is true $\implies$ (3) is true. But what about other options due to partial behaviour in $x$ and $y$?